# Error with SecKeychainGetPath

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes when trying to get a path to a keychain returned by `SecKeychainCopySearchList` I get error with code `-25301` which from the list of errors stands for `errSecBufferTooSmall`. The `SecCopyErrorMessageString` states:

```
There is not enough memory available to use the specified item.
```

Weird thing is that it doesn't always return the error on the very same keychain reference.

Here's how I try to get the path to the keychain:

```
- (NSString *)getKeychainPath:(SecKeychainRef)keychain {
    char *pathName = malloc(sizeof(*pathName) * 1024);
    UInt32 pathLength;
    OSStatus errCode = SecKeychainGetPath(keychain, &pathLength, pathName);
    if (errCode != errSecSuccess) {
        NSString *errString = (NSString *)SecCopyErrorMessageString(errCode, NULL);
        DLog(@"%d: %@", errCode, errString);
    }
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:pathName length:pathLength];
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

I'm interested in what buffer does the function use? I've tried outputting the `pathLength` variable but it's way bellow the 1K bytes. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to avoid these errors? Can they be bypassed by any way at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`SecKeychainGetPath` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeychainGetPath):

> *ioPathLength*
>
> > On entry, a pointer to a variable containing the length (in bytes) of the buffer specified by `pathName`.
> >     On return, the string length of `pathName`, not including the null termination.

You're not doing the "on input" part.  You need to initialize `pathLength` to the size of the `pathName` buffer.  For example:

```
UInt32 pathLength = 1024;
char *pathName = malloc(pathLength);
```

Comment: Rob, curiously, Apple's own source shows something different.

Comment: Apple's source example at 
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/SecurityTool/SecurityTool-55109.1/keychain_list.c

 UInt32 pathLength = MAXPATHLEN;
 char pathName[MAXPATHLEN + 1];

Comment: Considering this dates back to OS 9, perhaps this weird API was intended to return the actual string size to make it easier to realloc or copy the minimum buffer needed and dispose of the rest?